# cscope does not save jumps to the tag stack when cscopequickfix is set to use quickfix

Tags: vim, cscope

Prior to setting cscopequickfix to use vim's quickfix window (via `:set cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-`), jumping to cscope tags (e.g. with `:cs find s`) would cause the jumps to be pushed onto the tagstack (see `:h tagstack`). When those jumps are in the tagstack, you can jump back to previous tags with `CTRL-T`.

After setting cscopequickfix, jumps don't seem to be pushed on the tagstack (verified with `:tags`). This presents a problem because now I can't jump between tags.

How can I get cscope tag jumps pushed onto the tagstack when cscopequickfix is configured to use the quickfix window?

---

FYI, the best workaround I have atm is to use the jump list instead (`CTRL-O`).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you added `g-` also in the `cscopequickfix` list, you should not get this problem. `g-` will take over the tags. So, instead of putting in taglist it will be put in jumplist. That is the reason `CTRL-O` works as its meant for jumplist.

Comment: isn't this a bug? Before setting the cscopequickfix it pushes to tagstack, why should it change the behaviour when setting cscopequickfix ? If I type `:cs f g symbol`, I can return using ctrl-t , but this changes when cscopequickfix is set, I can't understand the reason to change the behaviour